# click on placemark kml file not the exact position of the placemark

Tags: google-maps, kml

I've added an click handler to a kmlLayer which places an marker on the location clicked on one of the lines (placemarkers)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {
    if (kmlEvent.featureData.description != undefined) {
        var data = kmlEvent.featureData;
        var text = data.description;
        var latlong = kmlEvent.latLng;
        var gId = data.id;
        var roadId = data.name;
        var roadName = roadId.split(",")[0];
        resetMarker(selectedmarker);
        showNewMarker(latlong, gId, roadId, roadName);
     }
});
```

I place a marker based on the latLng received from the kmlEvent. It looks like the marker is placed on the line, but when I zoom in further the marker stands further from the line.

I think the latLng in the event is the exact location where is clicked on the map, not the coordinates of the placemark itself.

Are there any solutions to get the exact latLng of the placemark?So the position of the marker would be exactly on the placemark, no matter how much is zoomed in.

Comment: You probably need the coordinates of the polyline.  You may need to use a third party parser for the KML or a FusionTablesLayer (so you can query the FUsionTable for that data) to get that.  Then you can calculate the nearest position on the polyline.  Don't think there is anyway to do that at present with a KmlLayer.  Possibly you could add the polyline data to the featureData.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now know in which direction I should look.

Comment: Another option might be to open an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) with an example that shows the problem and a link to this question.  Wouldn't necessarily expect a timely response (but you might get lucky), and this certainly isn't the expected behavior.

Comment: Issue is posted on http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5702